# Php artisan make:auth not defined in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

When I am trying to run this command php artisan make:auth... The following error comes. Is there any way to run this command, or any alternative for this command, should I Install amy package for this command?

```
      Command "make:auth" is not defined.
    
      Did you mean one of these?
          make:cast
          make:channel
          make:command
          make:component
          make:controller
          make:event
          make:exception
          make:factory
          make:job
          make:listener
          make:mail
          make:middleware
          make:migration
          make:model
          make:notification
          make:observer
          make:policy
          make:provider
          make:request
          make:resource
          make:rule
          make:scope
          make:seeder
          make:test

Laravel Framework 9.8.1
```

Answer (score 9):

After Installing Laravel 9 you need to install laravel/ui package in order to generate authentication in laravel 9.

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

And than choose one of these

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Comment: I am a beginner, I did some work on just bootstrap. Which one should I choose?

Comment: you can choose: `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

Comment: habibi I have installed both of them successfully, but still facing the same issue, php artisan make:auth not defined

Comment: my command didn't run but it installed automatically

Answer (score 3):

After Installing Laravel 9/10 you need to install laravel/ui package in order to generate authentication in laravel 9/10:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

So after that you have give one of following package. It will depend on your framework familiar with:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Further, run bellow command for install npm:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Next run migration command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

All the required steps have been done, now you have to type the given below command and hit enter to run the Laravel app:

```
php artisan serve
```

Now, Go to your web browser, type the given URL and view the app output:

- **http://localhost:8000/**

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan ui:auth`. it worked for me. you can see it below commands.

---

```
Command "make:auth" is not defined.  
Did you mean one of these?
make:cast
make:channel
make:command
make:component
make:controller
make:event
make:exception
make:factory
make:job</p>
make:listener</p>
make:mail</p>
make:middleware
make:migration
make:model
make:notification
make:observer
make:policy
make:provider
make:request
make:resource
make:rule
make:seeder
make:test
ui:auth
```

If you didn't get style in auth pages use below link in tha layouts>path file

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32158816)

Answer (score 0):

Omer YILMAZ is right BUT!

It order to finish the UI installation proccess, you will need to install the right version of vite and nodejs.

Because Laravel 9 require vite3+ and vite require nodejs 14+ version

My case: WSL2 on ubuntu 20.04 i was needed to install

1. install nvm (to use different versions of nodejs)
2. install nodejs (16 is fine)
3. and only then, i was able to run successfully the command: `npm install && npm run dev` as needed.

I hope it helps